# Why doesn't my plane array align to a curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to align an array of planes to a curve using the curve modifier. However, instead of the planes following the track, they just build a straight line which crosses the starting point of the curve in a 90 degrees angle.

[image]

I made sure the plane and curve both have the same origin coordinates, using the Shift+S menu. I tried the "Rotation & Scale" thing in the Ctrl+A menu, made new and simpler curves to try it with, as well as move the curve around. There are countless tutorials for this, but all of those seem to do exactly the same thing as I did and it never worked for me.

Here's my blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/gpdf16ubpo3wy7l/plane_curve_issue.blend/file

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran into 3 gotchas.

- The transforms on plane and path were not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> applied. The object-level scale was sending deformed planes over the clipping horizon, which I also adjusted. As a general rule, while modeling, scale the *mesh* in Edit mode, rather than altering the *object's* transform.
- The 'Radius' checkbox was set in the path's curve data tab. This means the scale of the deformed plane-array was responding to the curve's radius, which was somewhere near 100. In Edit Mode, under the Transform panel, I selected all the curve's vertices and set the radius to 1.
- (Maybe not one?) The curve was not closed (cyclic). To toggle that, in Edit Mode, hit  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

Here's the file..

[image]

(BTW, on BSE, this is the preferred (dedicated) site for exchanging .blend files.)

Comment: I got it to work with your explanations. Thank you lots!